# Execute second function when the first has finished

Tags: javascript, html

In the code below, my idea is to show: The kingdom (clicked_id) attacks (clicked_id).

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I execute the second function (***kingdom(clicked_id)***) when the first function (***kingdom(clicked_id)***) has finished?

Code:

```html
<h2 id="attack"> The kingdom </h2>
<button id="Roma" onClick= "kingdom(this.id);"> Roma </button> <br>
<button id="Venecia" onClick="kingdom(this.id);"> Venecia </button>
```

```js
function kingdom(clicked_id) {

  var attack = document.getElementById("attack");

    attack.textContent += clicked_id;

    document.getElementById(clicked_id).style.display = 'none';

};

function kingdom(clicked_id){

    var attack = document.getElementById("attack");

    attack.textContent += " attacks " + clicked_id;

    document.getElementById(clicked_id).style.display = 'none';

};
```

Comment: You don't have to change the names of your function to be in English. In fact, since you changed the functions to `kingdom`, you are effectively overloading this function and it will likely only execute the second function. You could name them `kingdom1` and `kingdom2`, though.

Comment: Yeah, but when I change the functions to kingdom1 and kingdom2, which function I have to execute in the onClick of the buttons?

Comment: That's completely up to you. If you wanted to make the first one `kingdom1` and the second `kingdom2`, you would just need to call them as you intend from the `onClick` attribute in your html.

Comment: As you can see, I'm new in programming. But I want the first clicked button to be the one who attacks and the second clicked button to be the one who is attacked. I want to Rome attacks Venecia or to Venecia attacks Rome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the text to say `El reino ${clicked_id} ataca a ${clicked_id}`, you should create a single function that handles both cases (see the full code at the end) plus a reset button and function to reset the whole thing.

I created a boolean variable to keep track of the result

```js
var first = true;
```

Which gets negated at the end of each function call

```js
  first = !first;
```

---

I created a reference to the `attack` and `reset` elements once to reduce DOM calls

```js
const attack = document.getElementById("attack");
const resetButton = document.getElementById("reset");
```

---

Then, the function call references the element so that it can get the id and add the `.hide` class without using additional calls to the DOM with `getElementById`

```js
function doAttack(element) {
  element.classList.add("hide");
  var kingdom = element.id;
```

```html
<button id="sample" onclick="doAttack(this)">
```

---

If the `first` boolean is true, set the `textContent` to `"El reino " + kingdom + " ataca a "`. Then, when `first` is false, append `textContent` with the kingdom to achieve the result which I believe you're looking for.

```js
// Keep track of the current state
var first = true;
// Save a reference to the h2#attack element - reduce DOM calls
const attack = document.getElementById("attack");
// Save a reference to the button#reset element - reduce DOM calls
const resetButton = document.getElementById("reset");

function doAttack(element) {
  // element will reference the current element being called, due to doAttack(this)
  // Add the .hide class to the element to hide it from display
  element.classList.add("hide");
  // Get the kingdom name from the element's id
  var kingdom = element.id;
  if (first) {
    // Set the content on first kingdom select
    attack.textContent = "El reino " + kingdom + " ataca a ";
  } else {
    // Append the content on second kingdom select
    attack.textContent += kingdom;
    // Show the reset button by removing the .hide class
    resetButton.classList.remove("hide");
  }
  // Negate our boolean value
  first = !first;
}

function reset() {
  // The following iterates over all .kingdom elements and remove the .hide class so they show appropriately
  for (let element of document.getElementsByClassName("kingdom")) {
    element.classList.remove("hide");
  }
  // Add the .hide class back to the reset button
  resetButton.classList.add("hide");
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="attack">El reino </h2>
<button id="Roma" onclick="doAttack(this)" class="kingdom">Roma</button>
<button id="Venecia" onclick="doAttack(this)" class="kingdom">Venecia</button>
<button id="reset" onclick="reset()" class="hide">reset</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

These is normal JS functions, you can call them one by one, it will only start executing the second one after finishing the first code.
Javascript is single-threaded so it will only have one execution at a time

Note: normal JS will not wait for async operations like file operations or API calls etc...

first way is

```
atacante(click_id);
atacado(click_id);
```

second way is
Call the second function from where you need it and call the first function from second one

```
function atacante(clicked_id) {

  var atacante = document.getElementById("atacante");

    atacante.textContent += clicked_id;

    document.getElementById(clicked_id).style.display = 'none';

};

function atacado(clicked_id){
    atacante(clicked_id)
    var atacado = document.getElementById("atacante");

    atacado.textContent += " ataca a " + clicked_id;

    document.getElementById(clicked_id).style.display = 'none';

};
```

Comment: Alright, but how can I click one button without executing the two functions once?

Comment: add your button, html code in question so that we could understand your implementation

Comment: They're added. This is what I want: The kingdom (clicked_id of a button) attacks (clicked_id of another button, without repeating the same id). Then, as you can see in the script, the button when is clicked, is going to disappear.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand that requirement, please add some screenshots or add full code to slackbits

Comment: @Raúl If this answer successfully answered your question, you should mark it as the accepted answer and ask a new question.

Comment: I have published three pictures of the result I want to see.

Comment: So for the first time no need to add ' attacks ', and from second button click need to append 'attacks' and the button text right ?

Comment: That is not the thing. When I click a button, appears: The kingdom (clicked_id button) atttacks (clicked_id button). The "attacks" word could be in both functions.

Comment: So it's: I click button = the one who attacks. I click another button = the one who is attacked. Right now, if I click one button (e.j. Rome), it shows: Rome attacks Rome